# Mostrar imágenes en Laravel 10 / Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Estoy tratando de mostrar las publicaciones almacenadas en mi aplicación pero las imágenes no se muestran. He verificado que se están almacenando bien y lo hacen en storage/app/public/images, pero en la vista no las encuentra.

Así es cómo almaceno mis posts:

```
public function create() {
   $this->validate([
      'content' => 'required',
      'image' => 'required'
   ]);

   $image_path = $this->image->store('public/images');

   $post = Post::create([
      'user_id' => $this->user_id,
      'content' => $this->content,
      'img_path' => $image_path
   ]);
}
```

Y así las muestro en la vista:

```
<div>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="mb-2 card">
            <h3>{{$post->content}}</h3>
            <p>{{$post->img_path}}</p>
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/' . $post->img_path) }}" alt="Imagen del post">
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Revisa con el inspector el URL que tiene la imagen e intenta visitarlo, es muy probable que esté mal

Comment: @HeytalePazguato sí. De hecho, se me ha olvidado decirlo en la publicación, pero la url es “http://localhost/storage…” no entiendo ese localhost

Comment: te marca un 404 en la ruta ó algún código de error?

Comment: @JonathanG yes, me dice: GET http://localhost/storage/app/public/files/jajcqzpHCyYXO2pIYyiFdhFlFg4uI2rTlJbcy3y0.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Hola Antonio, que bueno que has solucionado tu problema, has puesto la solución dentro de la pregunta, para que sea de utilidad para otros, deberías editar tu pregunta, quitar de ella la respuesta, y agregarla como tal, en la zona de respuestas, así evitarás votos negativos y tal vez recibas algún **flechaParaArriba**.

Comment: @MarcePuente okey!! No sabía eso, así que muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

**YA LO HE RESUELTO!!**

Solución

> Ejecuté el comando php artisan storage:link, que crea un
> enlace directo con la carpeta public de storage, por lo que para
> acceder a las imágenes se debe hacer
>
> '<img
> src={{asset("storage/images/37DaEmnPZYnsjifWkaXyyNGC8eXILtjMe71vWGAj.png")}}
> alt="Imagen del post">'
>
> es decir, directamente al archivo o, en mi caso, la carpeta que lo
> contiene y el nombre del archivo.